# SQL query to get the most recent test records with particular characteristics for a specific serial number

Tags: sql, greatest-n-per-group

I am creating a view containing a series of test results from well known canned tests as well as custom tests. Buttons on the GUI drive the canned tests, text entry provide the custom tests. Standard % tests:2,5,10,50,75,100; custom: 0-100 as entered %.

```
SELECT        
    SerialNumber, ..., DateTimeStampStarted, 
    StartingSetpoint, EndingSetpoint... Status, Notes 
FROM 
    dbo.PIDTuneResults
WHERE        
    (DateTimeStampStarted IN (SELECT MAX(DateTimeStampStarted) AS Expr1 
                              FROM dbo.PIDTuneResults AS PIDTuneResults_1  
                              WHERE (StartingSetpoint = 0 
                                AND EndingSetpoint = 2)
                              GROUP BY SerialNumber))
```

This query returns one (2%) of the canned tests, I am repeating this query 6 times (UNION), to enumerate the canned setpoints 2,5,10,50,75,100. Each query returns 1 record...the last test performed on that device. Now I need the custom test results. Here is my attempt but I need the last record for any of the custom tests.

```
SELECT  
    SerialNumber, ..., DateTimeStampStarted, 
    StartingSetpoint, EndingSetpoint... Status, Notes 
FROM 
    dbo.PIDTuneResults 
WHERE 
    StartingSetpoint = 0 
    AND EndingSetpoint NOT IN (2, 5, 10, 50, 75, 100)
```

How can I get the Last record for any custom test with any ending setpoint value(1-100)? Is there a way to do an aggregated qry like the others?

Thanks, Dan

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add the tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `db2`, `sql-server`, ...

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using `sql server` since you reference some tables names with `dbo.`.  If so, here's one option using `row_number`:

```
select *
from (select *, 
      row_number() over (partition by EndingSetpoint order by DateTimeStampStarted desc) rn
      from dbo.PIDTuneResults
      where StartingSetpoint=0) t
where rn = 1
```

This will return a single row for each `EndingSetPoint` based on it's highest `DateTimeStampStarted`.  If you need to limit to those to just 1-100, you just need to add `where` criteria.

```
select *
from (select *, 
      row_number() over (partition by EndingSetpoint order by DateTimeStampStarted desc) rn
      from dbo.PIDTuneResults
      where StartingSetpoint=0 and EndingSetpoint >= 1 and EndingSetpoint <= 100) t
where rn = 1
```